# despliega la palabra index en lugar del archivo index.html

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

estoy trabajando con spring web, lo que pasa es que el ejecutar el localhost en vez de que me arroje el archivo index.html me despliega la palabra índex. El proyecto consiste en que en un archivo de html despliegue la fecha y hora actual adjunto el código de spring.

HoraApplication.java

```
package com.example.hora;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.Controller.HoraController"})
public class HoraApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HoraApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

ServletInitializer.java

```
package com.example.hora;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends  SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application){
        return application.sources(HoraApplication.class);
    }
}
```

HoraController.java

```
package com.Controller.HoraController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@RestController
public class HoraController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/index.html")
    public String index(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("tstamp", LocalDateTime.now());
        return "index.html";
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hora local</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hola spring boot hora local</h1>
        <p>La hora local de hoy es: <span th:text="__$_{__tstamp}"></span></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: ejecucion del programa]

Comment: Debes usar `@Controller` en vez de `@RestController`

Comment: ahora me sale el error 500

Comment: Tienes error en el servidor, comparte la traza para intentar ayudarte.

Comment: <p>La hora local de hoy es: <span th:text="__$_{__tstamp}"></span></p> es este el que estoy usando

Comment: Eso no es la traza del error. No obstante, la sintaxis que usas para el `th:text` no es correcta, debe ser `${tstamp}`.

Answer (score 0):

Te expongo un ejemplo muy parecido a tu caso.

**Main:**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

A diferencia con tu `main`, en mi ejemplo no utilizo la anotación `@ComponentScan`

**Controller:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class DatesController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String dates(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("tstamp", LocalDateTime.now());
        return "dates";
    }
}
```

**dates.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Spring Boot Thymeleaf Application - Working with dates</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Format dates</h1>
    <p th:text="${#temporals.format(tstamp, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')}"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Este archivo lo tengo alojado en la carpeta `src/main/resources/templates`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Revisa que tengas todas las dependencias necesarias para trabajar con thymeleaf.

**Output:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que este ejemplo pueda servirte y aclararte tus dudas.

Comment: hice las modififcaiones pero ahora me marca el error 400

Answer (score 0):

Estás utilizando un `@RestController` que es una anotación que agrupa `@Controller` y `ResponseBody`.

Por eso te sale el contenido directamente `index.html` en vez de renderizar la  vista.

Si lo cambias por `@Controller` debería funcionar como esperas.